# Foundation Zurb Navigation

Tags: navigation, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation zurb 3, and have a  [top navigation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php#topbarCode)
if browser is full screen the navigation looks fine, but when i compress it i have just black bar. Maybe some have such problem?

Comment: how does your source code look like?

Comment: http://pastie.org/6036714 and you can look here [link](http://5.175.191.226)

Comment: can you paste the relevant parts of the code in here or prepare a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a little while since I tinkered with Foundation, but I encountered similar issues when attempting to alter the screen width settings in the css files - I believe there are multiple settings which must be the same for the top-bar to work correctly.

To get this working right you must either:

- Download a fresh copy of the Foundation libraries from their website, setting the screen width using their customization tool (and don't change it thereafter), or
- Use the SASS version, and change the screen width variable in the SCSS files (I haven't actually done this so can't give further details).

EDIT:
Just looked at your code snippet - you might need to include a breakpoint, using the `toggle-topbar` list item class, e.g.

```
<li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough to tell what's going on without seeing your sample (link isn't working), but the best place to start tends to be to copy someone's working code into your file and see if it behaves properly. With that as a benchmark you can then compare it to your code to see where the discrepencies lie.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the width of the toggle-topbar from 50% to 100%:

```
.top-bar ul > li.toggle-topbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

to

```
width: 100%;
```

This website demonstrates this technique:

http://catch-ps.com/